# Extracting RSS feeds from FeedDemon

Tags: rss, feed-reader

I have access to an old HDD of mine that is currently connected to my PC. I can view the files and directories but cannot boot into that drive. I would like to retrieve my old RSS feeds from FeedDemon, however I cannot start up the program and simply export feeds.

Is there a config file that I can copy over to my new directory and restore my old feeds?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a config file that I can copy over to a directory and restore old feeds?

The feed data is an SQLite database, stored in FeedDemon's cache folder:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\FeedDemon\v1
```

The file is called `feeds.fdb`.

---

#### How do I repair a corrupt FeedDemon database?

> FeedDemon stores its data using SQLite, which is regarded as being very reliable even in situations that would cause other programs to corrupt their data (such as a sudden power failure).  However, in very rare cases FeedDemon's database may become corrupt.

...

> To repair the database, first open FeedDemon's cache folder, which contains your feed data.  If you haven't changed the location of the cache folder, you can find it by opening Windows Explorer and typing this into the address bar:
>
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\FeedDemon\v1

Source [FeedDemon FAQ](http://nick.typepad.com/feeddemonfaq/)